# Angular 2 - My sub routes dont open nothing

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I'm having two routes in my application .. One inside another, like: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMeGV.png)

When click on sub route, nothing happen

My code:

App.route.ts:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent}
];
```

App.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
...
```

App.component.html:

```
<nav>...
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Dashboard.routes.ts:

```
export const dashboard: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: EscapeGameComponent, outlet: 'subOutlet'},
      {path: 'boardGame', component: BoardGameComponent, outlet: 'subOutlet'}
    ]
  }
];
```

Dashboard.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(dashboard)
  ],
...
```

Dashboard.component.html

```
  <p [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { subOutlet: [''] } }]">Escape Game</p>
  <p [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { subOutlet: ['boardGame'] } }]">Board Game</p>
  <router-outlet name="subOutlet"></router-outlet>
```

Why when I click in `<p>`, nothing happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of wrong configuration and subOutlet which is not required.

> dashboard.routes.ts

```
export const dashboard: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: EscapeGameComponent},
      {path: 'boardGame', component: BoardGameComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

> dashboard.component.html

```
  <p [routerLink]="['/']">Escape Game</p>
  <p [routerLink]="['/boardGame']">Board Game</p>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Sorry to say that it worked, I was wrong, but it still did not work ..
The problem now, is that the subroutines work, but the main one does not ..
I can navigate boardgame and escapegame, but not between main route and profile

Comment: Change the order 'export const routes: Routes = [ {path: '', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', component: DashboardComponent}, {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent} ];'

Comment: Yeah! Now it worked! Thank you very much, but what does the order interfere in this case?

Comment: Angular routers start searching from the very first to next. Since in your current configuration `path: ''` will match with all the routing since it is empty `''` and it will stop moving to next path. You have other option to put `pathMatch: 'full'` to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

-add a `children` property to your parent route which is an array of routes, you must have a `router-outlet` inside the parent element, example:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: 'profile',
  component: ProfileComponent,
  children: [
   {path: 'settings', component: ProfileSettingsComponent}
   {path: 'followers', component: ProfileFollowersComponent}
  ]
 }
];
```

if the outlet is the only one in your component, then you don't have to name it.

Comment: Thanks Krim! I used Sunil's answer, and it worked.
But its worked too

Comment: Sorry to say that it worked, I was wrong, but it still did not work ..
The problem now, is that the subroutines work, but the main one does not ..
I can navigate boardgame and escapegame, but not between main route and profile